# a paid day/cOmes, goEs away quIck, So/much became/of a juco

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

The entirety of this puzzle is contained within the title. Your final answer should be a single word.

Comment: Does the slash indicate closeness or separation ? Meaning : Is "a paid day" one unit or "day/cOmes" is one unit ? Does the comma indicate separation ? Or it is not significant ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Starting Point:

> There are 4 CAPITAL LETTERS OEIS which refers to https://oeis.org/ where we can enter terms of Integer Series and get matching known series.

> Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out the terms because I am not sure where the separation occurs.

That was the crux of my earlier comment:
Does the slash indicate closeness or separation ? Meaning : Is "a paid day" one unit or "day/cOmes" is one unit ? Does the comma indicate separation ? Or it is not significant ?

Assuming slash is separation, ignoring comma:

> The terms are 143, 54452, 46, 214, where I am counting word length == Decimal Digit
>  No match

> The terms are 8, 20, 10, 7, where I am counting total word length == term
>  One match related to Farey, unfortunately, these are not Initial terms, hence not correct.

> The terms are 3, 5, 2, 3, where I am taking word count == term
>  400+ matches ; hence this too is not correct.

Assuming slash is closeness, ignoring comma:

> The terms are 1, 4, 35, 4, 4, 5, 24, 62, 1, 4, where I am counting word length == Decimal Digit and joining words with slash eg day/comes == 35
>  No match

Assuming slash is separation, comma is also separation:

> The terms are 143, 5, 445, 2, 46, 214, where I am counting word length == Decimal Digit and terms are separation with slash and comma
>  No match

Assuming slash is separation, ignoring comma, also ignoring the CAPITAL LETTERS:

> The terms are 143, 43441, 46, 214, where I am taking word length == Decimal Digit
>  No match

> The terms are 8, 16, 10, 7, where I am taking total word length == term
>  3 matches but not Initial terms, hence this too is not correct

Comment: I guess the DownVote indicates I am on a wild-goose chase ; Back to Square One !!

Comment: I suspect the downvote (not me!) is probably due to there not being much *positive* progress in the answer as it stands. The spot in the first spoiler is fairly self-evident, and the rest is a list of things you've tried that haven't worked. Overall, I can see why some might consider this to be 'a bit too partial'. However, I don't think you're on a wild goose chase unreasonably - I suspect what you're doing is the right kind of thing, it just seems to be the type of question that leads to lots of dead ends before you finally reach the actual answer. Keep trying! :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence @Stiv ! In my Post, I only wanted to state the "Starting Point" & I wanted to list what I tried, to show that I could not make Progress. Maybe there are more clues in the unusual wording : thinking , thinking , thinking !